# Display Posts by Author based on Custom Field Name

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to display the post title URL of a post by an Author.

I need to display this in 2 places

1) Dashboard (only logged in user can see this)

2) Public info on their public profile page

///

**1) Dashboard**

So the user will be logged for Dashboard so I am thinking I could get the Post URL based on the currentuser ID and echo it on the page?

I can figure out how to get the current user ID

```
get_currentuserinfo();
$userID = $current_user->ID;
```

but not sure how to get / echo the post title from there.

**2) Public Info**
So this will be in a public profile page. I want to display the Post URL for the Authors profile page that we are looking at.

On this profile template I am already displaying the user name like this

```
<?php 
echo get_queried_object()->display_name;
 ?>
```

So thinking I could somehow get the post URL based on this display name or another object I could query?

2 seperate questions in a way , but looking for some help in how to display this information.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use `get_author_posts_url($userID)`.

This will take you to (by default) `site.com/author/author-nicename/` and using the author.php template it will display posts by that author.

You need to echo this value, btw, like so:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url($userID); ?>"><?php echo $display_name; ?></a>
```

Comment: but I want to display the actual link to the post, not to a list of posts by the author...any other way of doing this?

Comment: How is this post created?  Authors can have many posts... How do you know which one it is?